# Xcode 6 beta 3 doesn't recognize things defined in the Cocoa module swift

Tags: swift, xcode6

Xcode just stopped recognizing types defined in the cocoa module in swift even though i used

```
import Cocoa
```

The app still compiles though, basically the "Use of unresolved identifier"s just go away until after the build succeeds.  The problem is that I cant debug my code when there are tons of errors showing up that aren't really there.  I tried linking with Cocoa.framework, but like I thought it wouldn't make a difference when using swift.

Do you know a workaround to prevent this?

Just to let you know i have tried reinstalling Xcode, cleaning the build folder, adding a bridging header, making a new project, and importing AppKit directly like this.

```
import AppKit
```

this just makes source kit stop working

Also it imports Cocoa just fine when in a playground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why this happened but after installing xcode 6 beta 4 I haven't noticed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Betas will be beta. Try pressing `Command+Option+Shift+K` to clean the build folder and clear out Xcode's caches. If you can reproduce this issue with a consistent base case, then consider [filing a Radar](http://filearadar.com) to report this bug.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue as I changed the platform "from the right side menu" to mac os instead of iOS.
Hope this could help.